# Split string without non-characters

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to split a string that looks like this for example:

```
':foo [bar]'
```

Using `str.split()` on this of course returns `[':foo','[bar]']`

But how can I make it return just `['foo','bar']` containing only these characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't like regular expressions, but do like Python, so I'd probably write this as

```
>>> s = ':foo [bar]'
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalnum() or c.isspace())
'foo bar'
>>> ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalnum() or c.isspace()).split()
['foo', 'bar']
```

The ''.join idiom is a little strange, I admit, but you can almost read the rest in English: "join every character for the characters in s if the character is alphanumeric or the character is whitespace, and then split that".

Alternatively, if you know that the symbols you want to remove will always be on the outside and the word will still be separated by spaces, and you know what they are, you might try something like

```
>>> s = ':foo [bar]'
>>> s.split()
[':foo', '[bar]']
>>> [word.strip(':[]') for word in s.split()]
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: This is probably more efficient than my answer (two less loops), though I personally find the logic of "remove unwanted characters, then split" to be harder to follow. Not sure why. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do `str.split()` as normal, and then parse each element to remove the non-letters. Something like:

```
>>> my_string = ':foo [bar]'
>>> parts = [''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha()) for s in my_string.split()]
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: could end up with some empty string parts this way.  better to remove non letters before splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass through the list `['foo','[bar]']` and strip out all non-letter characters, using regular expressions. Check [Regex replace (in Python) - a simpler way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490597/regex-replace-in-python-a-more-simple-way) for examples and references to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Use [re.sub()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace `:,[,]` characters and than split your resultant string with `white space` as delimiter.

```
>>> st = ':foo [bar]'
>>> import re
>>> new_st = re.sub(r'[\[\]:]','',st)
>>> new_st.split(' ')
['foo', 'bar']
```